# Running code including context in another class

Tags: android, android-context

I want to run below code in my `DownloadService` class when the download finishes:

```
Intent localIntent = new Intent("android.intent.action.ATTACH_DATA");
localIntent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(imagePath)), "image/jpg");
localIntent.putExtra("mimeType", "image/jpg");      
localIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
FullImage.this.startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(localIntent, "set as"), 200);
```

What do you offer me to solve my issue??

Comment: What do you want?There is no question in your question.

Comment: Please edit your post to include the relevant lines of your `DownloadService `

Answer (score 0):

Use `AsyncTask` and run above code in `onPostExecute(Result)`